# Android custom listview with clickable links

Tags: android, listview

In my Android Application I use a custom list view to display company branch information.Each company branch details are added to list view as elements.

The problem is Within each element in the list view have clickable textviews. I need to track which clickable textview in which element pressed by the user.

eg:

```
===============
click1
click2
click3
===============
click1
click2
click3
===============
click1
click2
click3
===============
```

If someone can guide me its great..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [this](http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2009/10/29/clickable-urls-in-android-textviews/) link, which talks about adding Clickable URLs in TextViews?

Also you could just set a TextView's clickable property equal to true:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:clickable="true"/>
```

And then in code, add an onClickListener:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick(View view) { 
            Toast.makeText(view.getId() + " was clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 

});
```

So if you need to track which one was clicked, you would use the view.getId() in the onClickListener.

EDIT: Also take a look at View.setTag() - this lets you attach ANY object to a View element. So if each listview item has 3 buttons, when building your ListView you could attach an int[]. The int[0] position could be the overall element number, and the int[1](http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2009/10/29/clickable-urls-in-android-textviews/) position could be the sub-element number within the listviews element.

Comment: if I click the click1 link and consider view.getId() it refers to all the click1 textviews(AS I am creating custom listview) in the listview

Comment: Ok then what exactly are you wanting to track? Is this some special listview? Is it an expandable listview with groupings?

Comment: This is a custom listview. I need to track which link the User exacly click(for example there are three click2 links in this example, out of those three which one I clicked??)...It can be the click2 link either in 1st, 2nd or 3rd element in the listview

Comment: Can you please explain how actually get use of setTag() method in this partucular example. Bit confusing...!!!

Comment: Do you have a custom adapter that extends BaseAdapter?